# Problem "Entry name 'META-INF/android.support.design_material.version' collided" Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, apk

I just duplicated my project,(I wanted to have 2 separate apps with minor differences). I changed package name and applicationId for the second one and it runs perfectly on emulator but when I try to generate signed apk I get this error :

```
Entry name 'META-INF/android.support.design_material.version' collided
```

while I can do this for my first app perfectly fine.

I tried Rebuilding and cleaning project several times but nothing worked.

Here is my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.apptest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:LondonEyeLayoutManager:1fb6469521'
    implementation 'com.github.leochuan:ViewPagerLayoutManager:v2.0.22'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro:FullscreenVideoView:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


}
```

If there is anything else I need to put here tell me please.
please help me and tell me what did I do wrong and what should I do.
thank you.

PS:Both apps have different keys.
PS:I tried deleting existing APKs too. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the cleanup and rebuild project:**

```
Menu -> Build -> Clean project
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
Build —> Rebuild Project
```

Rebuilding the project should solve it. But as it could not solve your problem, please see if in the app's output directory there is any app file. If yes, then please remove or rename it. It seems the android sdk failing to overwrite it for some reason. Or, you can delete debug and release folders from the app folder altogether and then restart the IDE.

And if none of the above fixes your problem, then in your apps build Gradle add below, and then Clean, rebuild your project.

```
packaging options{ exclude 'META-INF/android.support.design_material.version' }
```